# How to create menu with a logo in the middle using html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a navbar with a logo in the middle with the navbar item being the same distance from each other. Like this:

[image]

However, I am having a problem making my navbar responsive. As you can see from the screenshot the distance between the logo and links were not equal. 
[image]

```css
 header {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 7em;
  margin-right: 7em;
}

/* use media query to change the layout */
@media  (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    .nav {
        margin-top: -42px;
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(1), .nav li:nth-child(2) {
        float: none;
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(3), .nav li:nth-child(4) {
        float: none;
    }
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 id="logo">Logo</h2>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: you could try css flexboxes

Comment: If you would like an answer with less CSS rules I'v provided that aswell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use flexbox, checkout the basics of flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

I've updated your code to work with flexbox.

I've moved the logo into the `ul` element.

```
  <header>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><h2 id="logo">logo</h2></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

I've updated your css to use flexbox, notice `.nav` has a `display:flex` on there now.

```
 header {
  width: 100%; 
}

#logo {
    text-align: center;
  margin-top:0;
}

.nav {
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
}

.nav li {
  flex: 1;
    display: inline;
}

/* use media query to change the layout */
@media  (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    .nav {

    }

    .nav li:nth-child(1), .nav li:nth-child(2) {
        float: none;
    }

    .nav li:nth-child(3), .nav li:nth-child(4) {
        float: none;
    }
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

That should be enough to get you going. Heres the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OEgXWg)

Answer (score 0):

Updated the following CSS and kept header in the ul

```
    header {
      width: 100%; 
      margin: 0 auto;
    }


    .nav {
    text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .nav li {
      display: inline;
    }
    h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.nav {
text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
/* use media query to change the layout */
@media  (min-width: 768px) {
body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.nav li:nth-child(1), .nav li:nth-child(2) {
    float: none;
}

.nav li:nth-child(3), .nav li:nth-child(4) {
    float: none;
}
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">

<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><h2 id="logo">Logo</h2></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `flex-box` you can also use `grid`;

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.container div {
  grid-column: auto / span 1;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div><a href="#">Work</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">About</a></div>
    <div><h2 id="logo">Logo</h2></div>
    <div><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Social</a></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Now it doesn't matter how you set the width of the header all the items keep the same width.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a simple example using **position: absolute** to center the logo:

Here is the HTML

```
<header>
    <h2 id="logo">Logo</h2>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

And here the CSS

```
* { /*Replace this to enable margin and padding*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
}

.nav li {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 70px;
}
```

If the logo is an image (as I suppose) you can use this little trick:

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px; /*If logo height is 40px*/
    margin-left: -30px; /*If logo width is 60px*/
}
```

As you can see I use top and left to place the logo in the center and then rest the half of the width and height of the image to the margin-top and margin-left.

Here is an example if your logo is an image: https://codepen.io/Nacorga/pen/yEXaQO